# Why `a` is treated like 2D array also?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python programming. In this Python code first `a` is treated like what we call 1D array in **C**. But, in the middle it is treating it as a 2D array!

```
n=int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
a=[]
for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    a[i].append(1)
    for j in range(1,i):
        a[i].append(a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j])   #this line
    if(n!=0):
        a[i].append(1)
for i in range(n):
    print("   "*(n-i),end=" ",sep=" ")
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print('{0:6}'.format(a[i][j]),end=" ",sep=" ")
    print()
```

I am not getting this idea. Can anyone explain what is happening in the line I have commented `#this line`(line number 7)? Thanks.

Comment: `a` starts out as an array, then an *array* is appended to it (`a.append([])`). A 2D array is still a ‘1D array’ of arrays. Since Python doesn’t require that you declare what an array will contain, there’s no need for C-like things like `a[][]`.

Comment: Ooh, I thought `a.append([])` makes `[ [ ] ]`, thanks

Comment: Yeah, which is what you call a 2D array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is dynamically typed and that's the reason why this is possible. The array (in python this is called a list) a can contain multiple list and values.

```
a=[1,"a",["abc",10]]
# Here you get the "abc" by calling
print(a[2][0])
```

In your example, here you append a list:

```
n=int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
a=[]
for i in range(n): 
    a.append([]) # <---- insert a list into the list
```

The last line above makes the list `a` a 2D list.

If you come from C, you are probably familiar with linked lists being implemented as containing a `void *` value in each node. This is the same as assigning the value of a node to the head of another linked list.